# SQL query -> normal english

Tags: sql, triggers

Can someone please help me put this query in to normal English. No technical terms needed.
This is a past paper question from an exam and it says "Explain in English what the following fragment of code does" Thanks.

```
CREATE TRIGGER SimpleTrigger
AFTER UPDATE OF Quantity ON Stock
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (:new.Quantity < 10)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Reorder(StockCode, StockName, Quantity)
    VALUES (StockCode, StockName, 100);
END;
```

Comment: The syntax is pretty readable as English "as is" IMO.

Comment: The only non-English words there are 10 and 100 :)

Comment: I am sorry but this is a past paper question from an exam and it says "Explain in English what the following fragment of code does".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever an update is applied to the column `Quantity`  in the table `Stock` and the 
new value of `Quantity` is less than 10, I want to insert a new row into the table `Reorder`.

To set the values for the new row in `Reorder` copy the values from the columns `StockCode` and `StockName`, for the updated row, to their corresponding columns and set the value of `Quantity` to be 100.

If you are studying for an exam, I suggest you phrase questions

`does code XYZ mean Blah Blah Blah.`

It will stick better.